# Just running elixir instead of packaging it

Tags: elixir

Would it be commendable to just run elixir from .beam files and scripts using a batch file?

Is there any downside for the end user?

Why should I use mix or any other elixir application packager?

please elaborate and argument.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an excerpt from the `mix release` [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/1.12/Mix.Tasks.Release.html). You can read the full document to get further information.

> ### Why releases?
>
> Releases allow developers to precompile and package all of their code
> and the runtime into a single unit. The benefits of releases are:
>
> - Code preloading. The VM has two mechanisms for loading code:
>   interactive and embedded. By default, it runs in the interactive
>   mode which dynamically loads modules when they are used for the
>   first time. The first time your application calls `Enum.map/2`,
>   the VM will find the `Enum` module and load it. There’s a downside.
>   When you start a new server in production, it may need to load
>   many other modules, causing the first requests to have an unusual
>   spike in response time. When running in Erlang/OTP earlier than 23,
>   the system always runs in embedded mode. When using Erlang/OTP 23+,
>   they run in interactive mode while being configured and then it
>   swaps to embedded mode, guaranteeing your system is ready to handle
>   requests after booting.
> - Configuration and customization. Releases give developers fine
>   grained control over system configuration and the VM flags used
>   to start the system.
> - Self-contained. A release does not require the source code to be
>   included in your production artifacts. All of the code is precompiled
>   and packaged. Releases do not even require Erlang or Elixir in your
>   servers, as it includes the Erlang VM and its runtime by default.
>   Furthermore, both Erlang and Elixir standard libraries are stripped
>   to bring only the parts you are actually using.
> - Multiple releases. You can assemble different releases with
>   different configuration per application or even with different
>   applications altogether.
> - Management scripts. Releases come with scripts to start, restart,
>   connect to the running system remotely, execute RPC calls, run as
>   daemon, run as a Windows service, and more.